# How to run `xterm` without getting a “Can't open display” error message?

Tags: macos, xquartz

On OS X 10.9.2 with XQuartz installed, I get the following message whenever I try to launch an xterm from **Terminal.app**:

```
$ xterm
xterm: Xt error: Can't open display: :0.0
```

How can I run `xterm` properly?

Comment: What does “I get” means? Do you mean that, in a terminal from Terminal.app, you type `xterm` at the prompt and get that message as an answer?

Comment: yes, exactly, something like   " xterm -e ssh  aaa@bbb.ccc"

Comment: Have you tried running XQuartz directly from the **Applications > Utilities** folder?

Comment: yes, than it runs for a couple of days, even saying in a terminal xterm -e ssh aaa@bbb.ccc after that I have to kill XQuartz, restart it, can open via Xquartz an xterminal, but not in a aterminal from Terminal.app via "xterm"